# Using autoplotly to produce an interactive plot for a ggfortify object used on a linear model

Tags: ggfortify

I am trying to produce an interactive plot for a `ggfortify`object based on a multivariate regression model based on this [data](https://app.box.com/s/lxr1iol1t2d8cqnjsfnv1ir2s7uqpi1x). Below is what I have done so far. How can I produce interactive plots for this `ggfortify` object by using `autoplotly`?

```
library(ggfortify)
library(autoplotly)

# Construct a simple multivariate regression model 
# So it's something like this SWE ~ Mean.Z + Intensity.mean

Model = lm(formula = SWE ~ Mean.Z + Intensity.mean, data = df.mean.swe)

# Plot the model
lm.plot = autoplot(Model, label.size = 3) + theme_bw()

# Interactive
autoplotly(lm.plot)

Error in unique.default(x) : 
  unimplemented type 'expression' in 'HashTableSetup'
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I was able to get rid of the problem by first specifying the the plots of interest to fortify.Though, I don't know why the error went away now.

```
lm.plot = autoplot(Model, label.size = 3, which = 1:2) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

But now `autoplotly` is not showing the Q-Q plot properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `shareY` argument tells the function whether or not to share y-axis among subplots.

Try this:

```
autoplotly(lm.plot, shareY = FALSE)
```